# Spyder Launch Error [UnicodeDecodeError] : ubuntu 14.04; Anaconda4.2; Python 2.7.12; Spyder 3

Tags: python-2.7, spyder

When I run spyder on command line, I got error message like below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/home/park/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py",
line 2998, in main
    mainwindow = run_spyder(app, options, args)   File "/home/park/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py",
line 2902, in run_spyder
    main.setup()   File "/home/park/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py",
line 1153, in setup
    self.setup_layout(default=False)   File "/home/park/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py",
line 1414, in setup_layout
    self.setup_default_layouts('default', settings)   File "/home/park/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py",
line 1593, in setup_default_layouts
    widget.toggle_view(True)   File "/home/park/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/plugins/ipythonconsole.py",
line 677, in toggle_view
    self.create_new_client(give_focus=False)   File "/home/park/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/plugins/ipythonconsole.py",
line 886, in create_new_client
    self.connect_client_to_kernel(client)   File "/home/park/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/plugins/ipythonconsole.py",
line 903, in connect_client_to_kernel
    km, kc = self.create_kernel_manager_and_kernel_client(connection_file)   File
"/home/park/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/plugins/ipythonconsole.py",
line 1276, in create_kernel_manager_and_kernel_client
    kernel_manager._kernel_spec = self.create_kernel_spec()   File "/home/park/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/plugins/ipythonconsole.py",
line 1256, in create_kernel_spec
    uv = to_text_string(v)   File "/home/park/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/py3compat.py",
line 136, in to_text_string
    return unicode(obj) UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 73: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have been searching the solution but I can not get the solution.
I have tried :

1. Reinstall using "pip install spyder"
2. Reinstall using "conda install spyder"

How do I fix it. If you give me some ideas, I can really appreciate for this.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you get if you open a terminal (command prompt) and type: `locale charmap` ? And did you try to reset Spyder?
For what I can understand, the error is happening when Spyder tries to encode some data to unicode. The data in question would be paths to spyder files, python files, and your saved files. Python assumes an ascii encoding and Spyder is keeping its assumption in `to_text_string`, but this appears to be incorrect in some of the data.  So there might be a path that has non-ascii characters that's triggering a bug.

Comment: ...TL;DR resetting Spyder (`spyder --reset`) could possibly allow it to open again, if I'm right and if the non-ascii path that triggered this (possible) bug was in a filesave of yours. Otherwise, I'm sorry, I don't know; but I'm still curious about the output of `locale charmap`; it might provide a way to fix it for now.

Comment: @Roberto 
Thank you Roberto. 
1. the result of locale charmap is "UTF-8"
2. I have tried "spyder --reset" and restarted spyder but it showed me the same error.

Comment: I see. I suppose @pyan is right and Spyder 2 might be a better option for now; Spyder 3 might just have a bug there. However, if you're willing to change Spyder's code (it's coded in Python), perhaps we could fix it. Would you be interested in trying?

Comment: @Roberto Thank you Roberto. I just try pyan method below. I removed my Spyder and reinstall downgrade version. When I reinstall spyder=2.3.9 I got PyQt Error. 
So I tried https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2699 to solve PyQt version problem.

Comment: Was the issue solved then?

Answer (score 1):

I also had some problems with Spyder 3 on Ubuntu 14.04. So I uninstalled it and reinstalled Spyer 2, which then worked just fine for me. If you don't mind using Spyder 2, you can run the following command to see if it works for you

`conda install -c spyder-ide spyder=2.3.9`

Comment: Thank you. I tried many things. But I made up mind downgrade my Spyder. When I tried your suggestion. First I got PyQt Version problem. I had to downgrade PyQt too. So I refered this issues [link] (https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2699). Thank you.